# What is the asymptotic running time of this pseudocode?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

In the following piece of code, `f()` is any function taking time of Θ(1). The time complexity should be Θ(n<sup>4/3</sup>), can someone explain why?

```
for(int i = 1; i ≤ n; i = 2∗i) {
    for(int j = 1; j∗j∗j ≤ n; j = j+1) { 
        for(int k = 1; k ≤ i∗i; k = k + i) {
            f();
        }
    }
}
```

By my analysis, the first `for` loop takes Θ(log<sub>2</sub> n) time, the second `for` loop is Θ(n<sup>1/3</sup>), and the third `for` loop is Θ(i). So in total we have Θ((log<sub>2</sub> n) × n<sup>1/3</sup> × i).

Since i can be n, we have Θ((log<sub>2</sub> n) × n<sup>1/3</sup> × n) = Θ(n<sup>4/3</sup> log<sub>2</sub> n). Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bound is not tight, because you counted `i` as Θ(n), but `i` is not Θ(n) on average. Consider the sequence of values that `i` takes, and add these up to count the total number of iterations for the inner loop. We can ignore the middle loop over `j` for now, since it is independent of `i` and `k`.

The sequence of values for `i` is 1, 2, 4, 8, ... up to n. If we say n = 2<sup>r</sup> for some r, this is a geometric progression with sum 2<sup>r+1</sup> - 1, which is about twice as big as n, so it's Θ(n). This counts both the outer and inner loop; the middle loop gives another factor of Θ(n<sup>1/3</sup>), and hence the overall complexity is Θ(n<sup>4/3</sup>) as required.